# FirebaseApp.configure() crashes for unit test target

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, xcode9.3

I've encountered a strange problem where the `FirebaseApp.configure()` call causes my app to instantly crash for my unit test target. It runs just fine for my standard builds.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's the stack trace:

```
2018-04-18 11:42:57.252405+0100 Avalanche[14289:124354] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40007000 started
2018-04-18 11:42:57.252454+0100 Avalanche[14289:124361] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2018-04-18 11:42:57.252712+0100 Avalanche[14289:124354] 4.8.1 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://googl/RfcP7r)
2018-04-18 11:42:57.371588+0100 Avalanche[14289:124278] [Crashlytics] Version 3.9.3 (128)
2018-04-18 11:42:57.390507+0100 Avalanche[14289:124278] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException', reason: '[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113c0a1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011329f031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113c7f975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Avalanche                           0x000000010f654dec -[Fabric validFabricConfigFromInfoPlist:] + 353
    4   Avalanche                           0x000000010f654a16 -[Fabric fabricConfig] + 127
    5   Avalanche                           0x000000010f654bce -[Fabric APIKey] + 392
    6   Avalanche                           0x000000010f61e6d7 -[Crashlytics APIKey] + 55
    7   Avalanche                           0x000000010f62a087 -[CLSCrashReportingController APIKey] + 57
    8   Avalanche                           0x000000010f62977f -[CLSCrashReportingController startWithProfilingMark:betaToken:] + 257
    9   Avalanche                           0x000000010f61e088 __20-[Crashlytics start]_block_invoke + 637
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b93779 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b94c0a dispatch_once_f + 55
    12  Avalanche                           0x000000010f61de05 -[Crashlytics start] + 106
    13  Avalanche                           0x000000010f61e23a +[Crashlytics initializeIfNeeded] + 48
    14  Avalanche Tests                     0x0000000129cd440a __15+[Fabric with:]_block_invoke + 538
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b93779 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000114b94c0a dispatch_once_f + 55
    17  Avalanche Tests                     0x0000000129cd41ee +[Fabric with:] + 222
    18  Avalanche Tests                     0x0000000129cd5dea __14+[Fabric load]_block_invoke + 580
    19  Foundation                          0x0000000112cc0324 -[__NSObserver _doit:] + 298
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ba5b8c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ba5a65 _CFXRegistrationPost + 453
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ba57a1 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 225
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113b67422 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113b665a1 _CFXNotificationPost + 609
    25  Foundation                          0x0000000112c80e57 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    26  Avalanche                           0x000000010f6d41a7 +[FIRApp sendNotificationsToSDKs:] + 393
    27  Avalanche                           0x000000010f6d309e +[FIRApp configureDefaultAppWithOptions:sendingNotifications:] + 302
    28  Avalanche                           0x000000010f6d2eda +[FIRApp configure] + 380
    29  Avalanche                           0x000000010f609490 _T09Avalanche11AppDelegateCACycfc + 192
    30  Avalanche                           0x000000010f6094c3 _T09Avalanche11AppDelegateCACycfcTo + 19
    31  UIKit                               0x00000001109eb6c4 _UIApplicationMainPreparations + 1491
    32  UIKit                               0x00000001109eb087 UIApplicationMain + 111
    33  Avalanche                           0x000000010f60b447 main + 55
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000114c08955 start + 1
)
li
```

bc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Before the crash, I also see a large number of log entries like:

```
objc[14289]: Class RCNKeyValue is implemented in both /Users/sammcneilly/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E62EC87E-0B07-4A83-A165-819E693AEB87/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6C3F993F-4CEB-462F-9257-0F3C8E088BC0/Avalanche.app/Avalanche (0x10f7bdd50) and /Users/sammcneilly/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Avalanche-ewiqmxxekhpknrhhfuyljlekgzat/Build/Products/Development-iphonesimulator/Avalanche.app/PlugIns/Avalanche Tests.xctest/Avalanche Tests (0x129e075d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I've installed Firebase and Firebase/Crashlytics via CocoaPods.
I'm not sure if this is related to Xcode 9.3 - this is happening on two separate projects, and I'm fairly certain it didn't happen previously for the older project.

I've printed out the bundle contents and the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file appears to be there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your issue with `Info.plist` file --> `[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.`

Comment: I don't think this is required for Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)? Additionally, I'm not sure how that value being missing would cause a crash *only* for the unit test target?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so this turned out to be caused by an incorrectly-configured Pod file.
My main target and unit test target were configured to use the following pods:

```
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.1'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.6'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 4.8'
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig', '~> 2.1'
```

Removing the additional Firebase pods for the test target ONLY (other than `Firebase/Core`) and running `pod install` again helped.

I'm not altogether sure **why** this worked, so would be very grateful if someone could explain this to me.

The `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` build phase script was configured on my primary target as detailed in Google's docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started, and adding it to the test target didn't help either...

Thanks to everyone for their input, but adding the `Fabric` details manually to the `Info.plist` file just caused a build error. I believe this step is automatically handled for Firebase.

Comment: Awesome thanks, removing Crashlytics and Fabric from the test targets solved it

Comment: I have the same issue but I use SPM to add Firebase into SwiftUI project. Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

We had the same crash when running XCTest. We use the following to get around it.

```
        if NSClassFromString("XCTest") != nil {
            return true
        } else {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code in info.plist**

```
<key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>YOUR APIKEY</string>
        <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>KitInfo</key>
                <dict/>
                <key>KitName</key>
                <string>Crashlytics</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Hope it's helps.!

Comment: It looks like the OP is using Fabric via Firebase, which doesn't provide the Fabric keys.